# How to turn a confidence set into a confidence interval

Tags: regression, confidence-interval

Element of Statistical Learning equation 3.15 states that the confidence set is
$$
\{\beta: (\hat{\beta}-\beta)^T X^T X (\hat{\beta} - \beta) \leq \sigma^2 \chi^2 \} \>.
$$

How do I turn this into a confidence interval?

Comment: I've edited your post to try to convert the math to $\LaTeX$. Please check, if you don't mind, to make sure I haven't introduced an error. Welcome to the site. :)

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you wondering how to move from a confidence region for the entire parameter vector to a confidence interval for a *single* element of the vector?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The confidence region for all \beta will be larger. I'm want to know by how much.